# .NET 8 MAUI & Push notification: what to do?

Tags: c#, android, ios, push-notification, maui

I'm creating an application with .NET 8 MAUI, and I like adding push notifications. Although I'm a big fan of Microsoft, the experience is quite frustrating.

It is more than 2 weeks that I tried to configure [Azure Notification Hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77930377/net-8-maui-and-azure-notification-hub-configuration-is-not-working) and paying the Azure support, I still can't configure the hub for Windows and Android doesn't seem working. So, at this point I tried other plugin but I have to ignore the Windows notification (sigh!).

I tried:

- [FirebasePushNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/Plugin.FirebasePushNotifications) but unfortunately this plugin doesn't have documentation and has an error at least with `.NET8` and the error is

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.installations\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Installations.resources\FirebaseInstallations.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseInstallations.framework\Headers\FirebaseInstallations-umbrella.h'.

- [Plugin.FirebasePushNotification](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) but unfortunately it doesn't seem that it works. I added [all the code](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/samples/FirebasePushSample.Android/MainApplication.cs) in the Android project and no notification from the Firebase portal.
- [Plugin.Firebase](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase) but also this plugin has the issue with missing files and the error is

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.installations\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Installations.resources\FirebaseInstallations.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseInstallations.framework\Headers\FirebaseInstallations-umbrella.h'.

- I followed the implementation of [Vladislav Antonyuk](https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/.NET-MAUI-Push-Notifications-using-Azure-Notification-Hub.-Part-2.-Setup-.NET-MAUI/) but at the moment it is not working for me
- I read some comments on GitHub where Microsoft said that the push notification is embedded in MAUI but I can't find any further documentation

Just to be sure and clear, I tried to send test messages from the Firebase portal like in the following screenshot.

[image]

Is it possible to implement Push Notification in .NET 8 MAUI? How?

Comment: "Is it possible to implement Push Notification in NET8 MAUI? How?" Yes! It's an extensive topic that I still want to cover in (a) video(s), but over the Christmas break I have made it work with Shiny and Azure Notification Hub. I can't be much more of help right now unfortunately, but just wanted to let you know this is definitely possible!

Comment: This is encouraging  I thought it was one of the simplest things to implement

Comment: Unfortunately not! It seems like a simple feature, but there is actually a lot to it, especially configuration. Once you've done it successfully it will become easier, but its a bit of a puzzle. I hope I can provide some content soon, but I'm sure you'll figure it out before that!

Comment: @GeraldVersluis do you use a particular NuGet package or implement your HTTP calls to register your devices and receive the push notification?

Comment: As mentioned, I used Shiny, more info here: https://shinylib.net/client/push/providers/#azure-notification-hubs

Comment: Oh I thought it was the `R` application for dashboards I think I found the way to register the device via APIs...

Comment: @GeraldVersluis struggling with this as we speak, looking at various outdated documentation pages from MS and other resources. I've looked at Shiny.NET but I must be missing something as I can't understand how to do the whole registration for Firebase and Azure NotificationHub in the app, update the native token to Azure NH for setting tags etc. Hopefully you'll be able to provide that video that explains it all for MAUI :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis if it can be useful, I fixed the problem and I documented all the steps for all platforms on this link https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/maui-push-notifications-using-azure-notification-hub-for-ios/